# Blazor Webassembly: System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, skiasharp, imagesharp, magick.net

I have a problem with static classes from image processing libraries in blazor webassembly. As soon as i use one i get a TypeInitializationException like in this screenshot:
[TypeInitializationException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCXYC.png)

I use the visual studio version 17.7.3 and .NET SDK 7.0.400 (x64)

And this is my solution config. if it helps:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
        <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="compilerconfig.json" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="compilerconfig.json" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="compilerconfig.json" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Blazor.SignaturePad" Version="7.4.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Blazored.LocalStorage" Version="4.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="BrowserInterop" Version="1.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="7.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="7.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="7.0.10" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Localization" Version="7.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="ReactorBlazorQRCodeScanner" Version="1.0.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="signaturepad" Version="1.5.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="ZKWeb.System.Drawing" Version="4.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Thanks in advance for the answers!

- Different .NET SDKs
- Different Visual studio versions
- dotnet restore
- Rebuilding and Cleaning
- Different Image Processing Libraries like ImageSharp, SkiaSharp, Magick.NET

Comment: 99% sure `System.Drawing` is not compatible with WebAssembly. 100% sure those libraries utilize `System.Drawing`. You are going to need to handle images server side or find a 100% WebAssembly compatible library.

Comment: AFAIK System.Drawing is not a .NET Core library. You cannot use it.